# Find the general solution to the DE $y ' = y/2t$ in implicit form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the solution to the following differential equation in implicit form.

$$ y' = \dfrac y{2t}$$

I am able to find a solution, but I belief it is explicit.

[image]

How do I convert an explicit solution to an implicit one?

Thanks.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing the link with an embedded image.

Comment: Where did you find this question? Asking you to write the solution in implicit form when you can write it in explicit form is meaningless.

Comment: This question was part of an exam question I am studying. I believe the point of trying to write in implicit form was to demonstrate the candidate knew what implicit form was and how to obtain it. From a practical perspective I agree it is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'implicit' form, but there's an error in your working where you write

$$ \int \frac{dt}{2t}  = 2\int \frac{dt}{t} $$

This is not correct and in this case it leads to the wrong form for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good job but you made a little mistake:
$$2\ln y= \ln t +c$$
$$y^2=ct$$
And not :
$$\ln y= 2\ln t +c$$